# Sharing videos using Facebook share button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I tried to share video using Facebook share button, but the video is not showing up and didn't share.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#share_button').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'Co-Operation Hub Hour Sharing To Your Buddy!',
          source : 'http://vimeo.com/user15830580/cooperationhub',
          type : 'video'
      };

  FB.ui(obj, callback);

   });

});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your entire code? There is no video file, but a folder called `cooperationhub`. Theoretically, there should be a link to the video itself. The link itself needs to be extracted: `http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=57406348`. That's why it won't share, least that's what I think.

Comment: Consult these links which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387128/get-direct-link-videos-from-vimeo-in-php and http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP-API039s/Get-video-thumbnail-from-vimeo

Comment: Check out the developers section also: http://developer.vimeo.com/

Comment: I added vimeo link in source and assign type is video. is it not good?

Comment: No, it needs the video's `ID`. Just the ending folder won't work. Consult their `API` section in the developers section of their website.

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick peak at the [Official Facebook Developer Docs for Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/).  This is the part of your code with the issue...

```
var obj = {
      source : 'http://vimeo.com/user15830580/cooperationhub',
  };
```

`source` *is not* on the indicated options for the API.

To share a URL, use `href`, as indicated in the official docs page....

```
var obj = {
      href : 'http://vimeo.com/user15830580/cooperationhub',
  };
```